# catfish indexer results via pipe or STDOUT?

Tags: linux, command-line

Is it possible to use catfish indexer via command line to make use of its results in conjunction with other programs or in a script?

e.g.

```
catfish --filename='john' --contents=='yoga' | grep -v bak
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, no. `catfish` is just a graphical front end to other programs:

```
DESCRIPTION
   catfish  is gtk2 python application that provides a graphical front-end
   to the  many  different  search  back-ends  such  as  locate,  slocate,
   tracker, beagle, strigi, pinoti, and find.
```

All it does is run other search tools and present their results in a graphical format. There's no point in having an option to print results to standard output in graphical frontend.

The best you can do is use one of the commands that `catfish` depends on and parse that. For example, with `locate`:

```
locate -b0 john | 
 xargs -0I{} bash -c 'grep yoga >/dev/null 2>&1 "{}" && echo "{}"'
```

Comment: your example isn't relevant (to me) because the power of a an indexer is in content indexing: i dont want to search the whole computer again and again for a word if i dont know the filename etc... i'll have to find the search-by-content back-end and find its command line...